# iOS CarPlay showing "Unable to connect" error

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

I am developing an iOS app that includes CarPlay usage. I have added the CarPlay entitlements given by apple to my app and when I launch the app it is shown in the CarPlay simulator as well, however when I run it I get the "Unable to connect to app" error screen.
I have implemented the AppDelegate configurationForConnecting callback as instructed and added my CarPlay scene configuration in the info.plist

AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        print(connectingSceneSession.role)
        if(connectingSceneSession.role == UISceneSession.Role.carTemplateApplication) {
            let scene =  UISceneConfiguration(name: "CarPlay", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
            return scene
        } else {
            let scene =  UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
            return scene
        }
    }
```

Info.plist (One of many combinations I tried)

[image]

However when I run the app the `configurationForConnecting` is only called once and only for `UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication` but It is never called for `UISceneSession.Role.carTemplateApplication`. Interestingly if I also open an external display in the simulator I do get the `UISceneSession.Role.windowExternalDisplay` in the callback.

Anyone else experienced a similar issue before?

Comment: In my app this seems to happen automatically since I don't implement this delegate function at all. Can you try commenting out the function?

Comment: hmm I tried it as well but doesn't seem to work =(. Do you mind sharing your Info.plist scene configuration?

Comment: Won't fit in a comment and doesn't make sense as an answer. I have `TemplateSceneConfiguration` and `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).CarPlaySceneDelegate` in the plist as config name and delegate class name, respectively. The app session role is almost the same (I have a `UILaunchStoryboardName`). You said your app appears on the CarPlay simulator, what happens when you tap the icon? Are your delegate functions called then?

Comment: When I click on the icon it opens the app and than it loads and gives me the "Unable to connect" error screen.Hmm weird not sure what it could be, I tried with that config also but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you download CarPlay sample code from Apple and check that it's not a problem with Xcode/the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Based on apple's sample code ([Integrating CarPlay with Your Music App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/integrating_carplay_with_your_music_app)), you should not initiate CarPlay's scene from AppDelegate, but from the class

> CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate

This the code part from the sample where CarPlay is connected to your scene.

```
func templateApplicationScene(_ templateApplicationScene: CPTemplateApplicationScene, didConnect interfaceController: CPInterfaceController) {
    MemoryLogger.shared.appendEvent("Template application scene did connect.")
    templateManager.connect(interfaceController)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, two steps solved the problem.  First, I needed to add

```
                    <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                    <string>UIWindowScene</string>
```

to my non-Carplay scene.  Second, I had to re-start the simulator.